# Mocha "$ is not defined" (Coffeescript)

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, coffeescript, mocha.js

We are just getting started with Mocha over here. We are writing our tests in coffeescript and testing our coffeescript files. However, we have hit a small issue. Here is the issue...

```
../userLogin.coffee:12
  $(function() {
  ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here is the test file:

```
chai = require('chai')
chai.should()

userLogin = require('../../private/coffeescripts/users/userLogin.coffee').userLogin

describe 'User login', ->
    it 'return true with valid credentials', ->
        userLogin('test@example.com', 'password').should.be true
    it 'return false with invalid credentials',  ->
        userLogin('invalid', '').should.be false
```

And here is the file we are using to run the tests:

```
# DOM READY =========================================================================
$ ->
    $("button#submitButton").on "click", loginSubmit

# jQuery ================================================================================
# Submit via the enter button
$(document).keypress (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
    loginSubmit()

# CoffeeScript Functions =================================================================
loginSubmit = ->
  emailInput = document.getElementById("emailInput").value
  passwordInput = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value

  # Check if either of the fields are empty
  if emailInput is "" or passwordInput is ""
    if emailInput is ""
      alert "Please fill in an email."
    else
      alert "Please fill in a password."

userLogin = (email, password)->
  true

root.userLogin = userLogin
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Testing jquery with mocha seems like a not-so-good idea. You should test page interaction with a browser-based test suite like casper and phantom. There's other problems here, like why would your login code user jquery? You should be separate out that code in such a way that it doesn't need jquery (since your login code should be server side).